# How to use special characters in Chef?

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am writing Chef recipes using `chef-solo`, where I need to run commands which include `+` but Chef returns an error if I use the `+` character.

```
bash "testing" do
code <<-EOH
/bin/grep '^+:' /etc/shadow >>/var/info
EOH
end
```

Method 1: put code in any  `script.sh` file and use it as:

```
execute " script running " do
  command "sh /path/script.sh"
end
```

but I don't want to use it. Is there any other way to use special characters?

Note: I tried using back-slash ("\").

**update** : got below error when i use code

```
bash "testing" do
code "/bin/grep '^+:' /etc/shadow >>/var/info"
end
```

Error:

```
 chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json
Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: test::test
  * bash[testing] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[testing]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150822-12224-kbivpd" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150822-12224-kbivpd" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150822-12224-kbivpd" returned 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /home/new/cookbooks/test/recipes/test.rb

  1: bash "testing" do
  2:   code "/bin/grep '^+:' /etc/shadow >>/var/info"
  3: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /home/new/cookbooks/test/recipes/test.rb:1:in `from_file'
bash("testing") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  command "\"bash\"  \"/tmp/chef-script20150822-12224-kbivpd\""
  backup 5
  returns 0
  code "/bin/grep '^+:' /etc/shadow >>/var/info"
  interpreter "bash"
  cookbook_name :test
  recipe_name "test"
end



[2015-08-22T19:49:52+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-08-22T19:49:52+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-08-22T19:49:52+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2015-08-22T19:49:52+05:30] ERROR: bash[testing] (test::test line 1) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150822-12224-kbivpd" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150822-12224-kbivpd" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150822-12224-kbivpd" returned 1
[2015-08-22T19:49:52+05:30] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem using

```
`/bin/grep '^+:' /etc/passwd >> /var/output`
```

this is ruby method to execute system command using backticks in which global variable `$?` is set through the backticks automatically

Comment: Warning, it will be executed at compile time and not at convergence time and won't be available as an audit report, and I really wonder why you don't rely on ohai attribute hash `node['etc']['passwd']` and filter it with ruby methods in this case.

Comment: i am generating audit report using another recipe

Comment: So take advantage of node attribute instead of redoing what is already done by ohai.

Comment: yes , i  used it many place in my recipes but i was just trying to use it different way . then i got this error and by sharing i learnt  about `exit status` that i  don't know. but any way thanks a lot  Tensibai .

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the + in the command !

There's nothing wrong, chef works as expected:

```
# grep '^+' /etc/shadow; echo $?
1
```

This command returns a status code of 1 as nothing is found (quote of `man grep` emphasis is mine):

> EXIT STATUS
>
> The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, **and 1 if not found**.  If an error occurred the exit status is 2.   (Note:  POSIX 
>   error  handling
>          code should check for '2' or greater.)

And chef tell's you exactly this:

> Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'

Reading the [bash resource documentation](http://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html#properties) we see there's a `returns` attribute with this description:

> `returns`  Ruby Types: Integer, Array
>
> The return value for a command. This may be an array of accepted
>   values. An exception is raised when the return value(s) do not match.
>   Default value: 0.

So if you want to accept this command return 0 or 1:

```
bash "testing" do
  code "/bin/grep '^+:' /etc/shadow >>/var/info"
  return [0,1]
end
```

So this may not solve your problem as you didn't describe what you're trying to achieve, we're on a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/287976) here

Answer (score 0):

Chef recipes are pure ruby, so you can write something like this without any problems:

```
bash "testing" do
  code "/bin/grep '^+:' /etc/shadow >>/var/info"
end
```

If you need to use double quotes inside your command, you can escape it with back slash "\".

Comment: You're not having problem with creating command, but executed command is retuned exit status 1. Are you sure that command that you have entered can be executed with success (works)?

Comment: yes , i able to run it manually , it is not returning any output now . but if these type of entry will remain in `/etc/shadow` then it will show that entry also . i found same problem in some other community but no reply was there or it may be chef not allow or may be other method to use.

Comment: If you're able to run this manually, maybe Chef isn't in good directory. Try add option `cwd` to bash resource, instead of using it in command. You can find docs here: https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html. Simply: place directory in `cwd` option, example: `cwd    '/etc/shadow'` and then just try using `grep`, without specyfying directory.